# Used up all my votes, but no Vox Populi badge?

Tags: support, badges

Twice since joining this site I have used up all my votes in a day.  I thought this should have earned me the Vox Populi badge, but it has not.  Is this a bug, or do I misunderstand the badge requirements?

Comment: I was able to get Suffrage and Vox Populi in the same day (I did kind of look for things worth voting on after I realized I'd gotten Suffrage... it was a slow Friday, I think). I didn't do anything but vote, so I doubt you misunderstand it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All I can think is, are you sure you used up **40** votes in a day, or just *all* of your votes in a day? As nonsensical as it seems, the latter could be less than 40. Something about how they added 10 extra votes that you can only use on questions, not on answers, but I'll be damned if I can explain how it works. What ought to work is to make sure your first ten votes of the day are on questions. (Yes, downvotes count.)

Comment: Yes, that might be it, I suppose.  Although I vote on questions pretty regularly.  I'll give it a try sometime soon.  There must be at least ten questions in that pile of 7K that I haven't read or voted on yet.

Comment: Actually, the rules are [really simple](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90202/please-dont-require-answer-votes-to-be-cast-before-question-votes/90256#90256). And by "really" I mean "not that".

Comment: This must have been the issue, because I earned the badge yesterday, and my count was surely at 40 votes.  Thanks!