# What is the "10 extra votes for questions" function?

Tags: discussion, badges, up-votes

I have gained both the "Suffrage" and "Vox Populi" badges, but I still don't understand the concept of the "10 extra votes for questions" function! The topic has been discussed on Meta, but I don't know how it works!

> Webpage: [Used up all my votes, but no Vox Populi badge?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1443/used-up-all-my-votes-but-no-vox-populi-badge/1444#1444)

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254598/248268 for the simple advice.

Comment: Cheers mate! My question was already answered by Andrew Leach, but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Voting is a network-wide thing rather than an ELU-specific thing, and I think this is answered by an Meta.SE question, [What's the difference between Suffrage and Vox populi badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90479/whats-the-difference-between-suffrage-and-vox-populi-badge/90480#90480). It's not possible to mark this question as a duplicate of that one because it's on a different site, but please do refer to it.

Suffrage: used 30 votes per day
Vox populi: used the maximum 40 votes in a day

Broadly speaking, you can vote forty times, but ten of those votes are reserved for votes on questions. You can only use these ten reserved votes *before* you've used 25 answer votes.

Answers on the MSE question mention a [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/) and [FAQ on vote limits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/) — it's complicated!

Comment: @AndyT Can you explain what was wrong with the answer? I don't understand it clearly. Does it mean if you used up all 30 votes just for answers, you can't vote 10 more times for questions?

Comment: @Rathony - Yes. Once you have voted on 30 answers, you cannot vote again that day, *even on questions*. Unless it's been changed in the past year anyway.

Comment: @AndyT I see. I didn't know that as I randomly vote. Thanks.

Comment: @Rathony - Actually.... it's more complicated than I just said. Follow the links to find out more. But Andrew Leach's original answer was very wrong, my revision made it less wrong (without getting too complicated). I've revised again, I think it's now right...